# Group collection based on the common values of a field mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

My collection looks like this

```js
{
"email" : "tp@sd.com",
"subscriptions" : [
                {
                        "default" : false,
                        "interval" : "weekly",
                        "tags" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "group-1",
                                        "value" : "g1-value-1"
                                },
                                {
                                        "name" : "group-1",
                                        "value" : "g1-value-2"
                                },
                                {
                                        "name" : "group-2",
                                        "value" : "g2-value-1"
                                },
                                {
                                        "name" : "group-3",
                                        "value" : "g3-value-1"
                                },
                                {
                                        "name" : "group-3",
                                        "value" : "g3-value-2"
                                }
                        ]
},
{
"email":"lol@xyz.com",
"subscriptions" : [
                {
                        "default" : false,
                        "interval" : "weekly",
                        "tags" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "group-1",
                                        "value" : "g1-value-2"
                                },
                                {
                                        "name" : "group-1",
                                        "value" : "g1-value-1"
                                },
                                {
                                        "name" : "group-2",
                                        "value" : "g2-value-1"
                                },
                                {
                                        "name" : "group-2",
                                        "value" : "g2-value-3"
                                },
                                {
                                        "name" : "group-3",
                                        "value" : "g3-value-1"
                                }
                        ]
}

}
```

I want to group this to an array of objects which contain emails and common group values.

for example, A user-1 has g1-value-1 and user-2 also has g1-value-1, maybe along with other values as well. But these users should be grouped together along with their tags. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can you please tell that what would be your sample output? I can make it work if I see the expected output. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly it's quite an easy query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$subscriptions"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$subscriptions.tags"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$subscriptions.tags.value",
            emails: {$addToSet: "$email"}
        }
    }
]);
```

The result will look like this:

```
[
    {
        _id: "g1-value-1",
        emails: [
            "tp@sd.com",
            "lol@xyz.com"
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: "g1-value-2",
        emails: [
            "tp@sd.com",
            "lol@xyz.com"
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: "g2-value-1",
        emails: [
            "tp@sd.com",
            "lol@xyz.com"
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: "g2-value-3",
        emails: [
            "lol@xyz.com"
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: "g3-value-1",
        emails: [
            "tp@sd.com",
            "lol@xyz.com"
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: "g3-value-2",
        emails: [
            "tp@sd.com",
        ]
    },
]
```